# &nbsp; is inserted when user control is not visible in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem I have no idea how to solve. I have a user control wrapped inside update panel which works fine, but when I set `userControl.Visible = false` AJAX response containts `&nbsp;`  which generates empty lines in IE 7 and 6. As you can imagine this accupy a lot of space when I have 30 hidden user controls. What should I do to prevent   to be sent with response?

Comment: it seems the control render itself as [space] if it is invisible. refer to 3-party of this control i think. what about FF? I have seen some hack of IE with space in it. i think it was done in that case <div>&nbsp;</div>

Comment: It's my control. A simple Asp.Net control. There is no code that handles visibility in any special way there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is how ASP.Net is designed. I had to add modify my source to use style="display: none" on invisible controls to prevent blank spaces to appear on the page.